# The latest docker on mac, 17.12.0-ce-mac46 (21698), hypervisor file system is read-only

Tags: macos, docker, docker-for-mac

With previous releases, I'm able to change the size of swap space by following below instructions.

https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-for-mac-configure-swap-space/20656/13

But with the latest release, I'm not able to do that any more, when I ran

```
echo "/var/swap.file swap swap defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

inside the hypervisor, I got an error instead, saying file system is read only.

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is mentioned in https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2389, a JIRA has been filed for future enhancement